# Django Model Relation entries

Tags: django, django-models, relationship, django-tables2, django-database

I have data and I want to organize it as:

I create three tables, on for  MonthsM, Wellinfo and TestPRODM:

```
class MonthsM(models.Model):
    MonthsM = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)

class Wellinfo (models.Model):
    WellID    = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)



class TestPRODM(models.Model):
    WellID    = models.ForeignKey(Wellinfo ,to_field='WellID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TestMonth = models.ForeignKey(TestMonthM, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TestOIL   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3,null=True, blank=True)
```

#conditions
In my real data I have one WellID that can be tested only once in month.

so how to set a condition that do that?

so in the table (TestPRODM) it can have many entry with same WellID but with different months
and so it can have many entry with same TestMonth  but with different WellID.

NB. NO entry in (TestPRODM) table that have the same WellID and TestMonth in the same time.

Updated POST

> ```
>     for i ,value in enumerate(PUITS):
>         try:
>             _, create = TestPRODM.objects.update_or_create(
>                 WellID= PUITS[i],
>                 TestMonth_id =obj.id,
>                 TestOIL =float(QHUILE[i]),
>                 )
>             print('Saving', PUITS[i])
>             AddedList +=[value]
>         except:
>             print('Passed', PUITS[i])
>             pass
> ```

and this function pass all restrictions in model and save all data in database!

Answer (score 0):

You make the combination of `WellID` and `TestMonth` unique, with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [wiki]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint):

```
class TestPRODM(models.Model):
    WellID = models.ForeignKey(
        Wellinfo,
        to_field='WellID',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    TestMonth = models.ForeignKey(
        TestMonthM,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    TestOIL = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=3,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['WellID', 'TestMonth'],
                name='once_per_month'
            )
        ]
```

prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class TestPRODM(models.Model):
    WellID = models.ForeignKey(
        Wellinfo,
        to_field='WellID',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    TestMonth = models.ForeignKey(
        TestMonthM,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    TestOIL = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=3,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together=[['WellID', 'TestMonth']]
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `test_month` instead of <s>`TestMonth`</s>.

Comment: I can't use UniqueConstraint I am using Django==2.0 and this method works only in up to 2.2

Comment: @tibas: that being said, 2.0 is no longer supported since August 2019: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Comment: Thank you, Your method works fine when I use Admin input of forms one by one.

Comment: @tibas: you can make a `TabularInline` to make editing objects in an m2m relation more convenient: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models.

Comment: I'd updated my post I am using a function in views.py to load data from Excel sheets and it load all data without exceptions